# How to make an existing type in an assembly to implement an interface in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, mono.cecil, duck-typing, load-time-weaving

How to make an existing type in an assembly to implement an interface (extract the interface then implement it) at run-time (using run-time weaving, Mono.Cecil, Common Compiler Infrastructure...)

Class in assembly:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public method1(){}
    public method2(){}
}
```

To generate

```
public class IMyClass
{
    method1();
    method2();
}

public class MyClass : IMyClass
{
    public method1(){}
    public method2(){}
}
```

Comment: What for? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: For a code analysis/refactor tool: to extract common methods into interfaces. To be used for legacy code migration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right, you can achieve this with for example Impormtu library (https://github.com/ekonbenefits/impromptu-interface, has nuget package also). Full sample:

```
internal class Program {
    private static void Main(string[] args) {            
        // suppose it's from another assembly, and you don't have direct reference to type
        var c = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(MyClass)); 
        IMyClass iface = c.ActLike<IMyClass>();
        iface.method1();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public void method1() {
        Console.WriteLine("Method 1");
    }

    public void method2() {
        Console.WriteLine("Method 2");
    }
}

public interface IMyClass {
    void method1();
    void method2();
}
```

Note that MyClass does not implement IMyClass interface, but you are using it as variable of type IMyClass at runtime.

If you don't have interface at compile time, and want to build *interface* also at runtime - then I don't understand how it can be used in real life.